# Can't overwrite adminhtml block

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides

I'm trying to rewrite some blocks from adminhtml (Magento 1.9.1.1). Here's my code in my extension's `config.xml`:

```
...
<global>
  <blocks>
    <adminhtml>
      <rewrite>
        <report_grid>Mypackage_Myextension_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Grid</report_grid>
        <widget_grid_column_filter_date>Mypackage_Myextension_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Filter_Date</widget_grid_column_filter_date>
        <widget_grid_column_renderer_date>Mypackage_Myextension_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Date</widget_grid_column_renderer_date>
        <widget_grid_column_filter_datetime>Mypackage_Myextension_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Filter_Datetime</widget_grid_column_filter_datetime>
        <widget_grid_column_renderer_datetime>Mypackage_Myextension_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Datetime</widget_grid_column_renderer_datetime>
        <report_sales_grid_column_renderer_date>Mypackage_Myextension_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Sales_Grid_Column_Renderer_Date</report_sales_grid_column_renderer_date>
      </rewrite>
    </adminhtml>
  </blocks>
</global>
...
```

Oddly enough, all blocks were overwritten except `report_grid` which is Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid.I couldn't find the issue. I have a file called `Grid.php` in `app/code/local/Mypackage/Myextension/Block/Adminhtml/Report`. What should I do? Is there any other way to rewrite this block?

UPDATE:

Here's output of `Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/blocks/adminhtml')->asNiceXml();`:

```
<adminhtml>
    <class>Mage_Adminhtml_Block</class>
    <rewrite>
        <report_grid>Mypackage_Myextension_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Grid</report_grid>
        <widget_grid_column_filter_date>Mypackage_Myextension_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Filter_Date</widget_grid_column_filter_date>
        <widget_grid_column_renderer_date>Mypackage_Myextension_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Date</widget_grid_column_renderer_date>
        <widget_grid_column_filter_datetime>Mypackage_Myextension_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Filter_Datetime</widget_grid_column_filter_datetime>
        <widget_grid_column_renderer_datetime>Mypackage_Myextension_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Datetime</widget_grid_column_renderer_datetime>
        <report_sales_grid_column_renderer_date>Mypackage_Myextension_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Sales_Grid_Column_Renderer_Date</report_sales_grid_column_renderer_date>
    </rewrite>
</adminhtml>
```

And this is my `Mypackage_Myextension_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Grid` class:

```
class Mypackage_Myextension_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        die("Houston the eagle has landed. \o/");
        $this->setTemplate('myextension/report/grid.phtml');
    }
}
```

But it never called. If I `die` in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid` it will die.

Answer (score 4):

This is very odd, do you have multiple rewrites ? Prefix your name to 'zzzzzzz' and the GLOB (xml  files) function will put your rewrite in as last. But maybe check the next line first:

Mage_Core_Model_Config: line(1227)

```
    $config = $this->_xml->global->{$groupType.'s'}->{$group};
    // First - check maybe the entity class was rewritten
    $className = null;
    if (isset($config->rewrite->$class)) {
        $className = (string)$config->rewrite->$class;
    }
```

So, you can do the next test/check:

Test:

```
<?php

include_once(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)).'/mageInit.php');

mageTest::initMage();
echo Mage::getConfig()->getGroupedClassName('block', 'adminhtml/report_grid');
echo Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/blocks/adminhtml')->asNiceXml();
```

Will give me this output when i copy/paste your XML in to my (empty) project:

```
Mypackage_Myextension_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Grid
<adminhtml>
   <class>Mage_Adminhtml_Block</class>
   <rewrite>
      <report_grid>Mypackage_Myextension_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Grid</report_grid>
      <widget_grid_column_filter_date>Mypackage_Myextension_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Filter_Date</widget_grid_column_filter_date>
      <widget_grid_column_renderer_date>Mypackage_Myextension_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Date</widget_grid_column_renderer_date>
      <widget_grid_column_filter_datetime>Mypackage_Myextension_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Filter_Datetime</widget_grid_column_filter_datetime>
      <widget_grid_column_renderer_datetime>Mypackage_Myextension_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Datetime</widget_grid_column_renderer_datetime>
      <report_sales_grid_column_renderer_date>Mypackage_Myextension_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Sales_Grid_Column_Renderer_Date</report_sales_grid_column_renderer_date>
   </rewrite>
</adminhtml>
```

**The best thing to do is stop using rewrites and the configuration part of Magento. And start using the Event-Driven part of Magento.** Especialy if your going to sell your modules to others.

Greating, good luck and happy hacking !

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are no other rewrites on this block. I tried your test in another way and it seems Magento won't overwrite my block. How can I find out why?

Comment: That isn't possible. If config says your file is called: `Mypackage_Myextension_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Grid` than that file will be used. (`Mage_Core_Model_Config` on line 1227). If you have a typo you will get a error like can't find : `MAGE_My...._My..._`, because if it doesn't exists like `Core` than it will prefix with `Mage` like: `Mage_Core`. And can't be a typo because i have copy pasted from you and it works. **Sorry to ask, but did you flush your config.xml cache ?** Please post: `Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/blocks/adminhtml')->asNiceXml();`

Comment: Also a good test you can try, but it's a ugly one. Open your block `/Adminhtml/Report/Grid.php` add a constructor with 'die("Houston the eagle has landed. \o/");'

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: Sorry, but the DIE schould be in the file your overwriting. Just to be shure where not trying to find a none-existing problem. What is the layout handle your using or are your creating the block in code ? I did not work with reports before, but i can't find a normal `adminhtml_report_grid` handle in report.xml (xml update files). Maybe a good test is to create the block from code in a unit test. echo get_class(Mage::getBlock('adminhtml/report_grid'));